# Moving documents in sub-folders using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to programming in python and I am having a bit of trouble with designing a particular code in python 3.6.  I am trying to extract certain files I have in a folder and place them in a corresponding folder based on values I have in a list.

For example, say in the folder "All", I have three sub-folders called A, B, and C.  In 'A' there is a files '123 - words', '768 - words', '921 - words'.  In my list, I have a unique identifier '768' (there is a lot more than one unique identifier in this list).  So, after the code is properly ran, it would pull the file '768 - words' from A and place it in a new folder created called 'A-1' (or whatever).  The code would do this for B and C as well.  All the file names I am trying to move/extract have the unique identifier at the beginning of the name.

Anything advice/help you can give is extremely appreciated.

Code:

```
valid_files = ['153'] # list would be longer
dir_src = 'source directory
dir_dst = 'destination directory'
for file in os.listdir(dir_src):
    for x in valid_files:
        if file.startswith(x):
            src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, file)
            dst_file = os.path.join(dir_dst, file)
            shutil.move(src_file, dst_file)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, or done any research around this? SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service, so this question is far too broad as it stands. See [ask].

Comment: Sure.  I added a code that works for an explicit folder.  But I would like it to loop through many folders and to have its own unique destination output based on the original folder.  I could use this code for every sub-folder, but I would rather automate the process.

Comment: Then search for that - Google "python loop through folders", or something.